# Why doesn't virtualenv virtualize arbitrary directories?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, virtualenv

So I have a Python script that I'm trying to distribute to Linux hosts.

In accordance with current best practices, I'm trying to deploy my script within a virtualenv sandbox. However, I noticed that virtualenv doesn't virtualize directories such as `/usr/sbin`, `/var/lib` and `/etc`. In accordance with Linux best practices, I need to write various files and configurations to the directories mentioned above.

How can I create a truly sandboxed deployment if virtualenv doesn't virtualize these directories?

Answer (score 1):

## Simple "install then copy/move" procedure

The procedure is simple:

- set up some virtualenv
- install in it the script of your interest
- move it to the directory you like, e.g. to /usr/bin

The trick is, that the script gets encoded path to virtualized python inside, so when you call it, it is using virtualized environment.

Usually, the encoding is absolute path, so moving the script file does not harm anything.

However, the directory with virtual env (where is the Python) must stay where it is, it is prerequisite for the script to run.

Installing the script must go via `setup.py` and must use parameter `entry_point`. Using `scripts` does not work, as it simply takes referenced file and makes simple copy only.

## Bonus: `setup.py` option `--install-scripts`

`setup.py` allows specifying, where to install the script. You might try using it (but this is not a requirement).

```
$ python setup.py install -h
Common commands: (see '--help-commands' for more)

  setup.py build      will build the package underneath 'build/'
  setup.py install    will install the package

Global options:
  --verbose (-v)  run verbosely (default)
  ....

Options for 'install' command:
  ....
  --install-scripts                    installation directory for Python
                                       scripts

usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help
```

## Conclusions

- virtualenv allows isolation of python environment for installed script while allowing simple copy/move of the script to whatever location incl. system directories.
- above is possible, if the script is installed using standard `setup.py`, which puts around the script references to virtualenv python. Copying plain python file would fail.
- `setup.py` even allows directly specifying where to install the script.

Comment: Yes, I'm indeed installing the script using `setup.py`. So I guess you also suggest we, as required, write files directly to the system's `/var/lib` and `/etc` directories? Doing so doesn't sound very *"sandboxed"* to me...

Comment: @AlfaZulu No, I do not propose to write the script directly to `/var/lib`. I only assume, the script gets (locally into virtualenv) installed by `setup.py`, otherwise it might miss the envelop refering to the python from virtualenv. The step, moving/copying installed script from virtualenv to system directories shall be done later on by another process (manually, by some enclosing installation script...). Anyway, `setup.py` shall has an option to specify, where to install.